# disabling security for dart unit tests with spawnUri to localhost

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-isolates

I'm attempting to unit test code that relies on spawnURI to an isolate running on a separate port on localhost (not self-contained, I realize).

Running the tests via `pub run test -pchrome` yields `SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'http://localhost:8064/test.isolate.dart.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://localhost:38643'.`  Tests work fine in vm/dartium.

Is there any dart/pub way to run browser tests with security disabled?  I know I can alias/override each platform executable or proxy the isolate, but is there a way to instruct pub test to use different executables or options?

Comment: Sounds you are spawning an isolate in the browser, right? What do you mean by "runnong on a separate port"? Sounds like a CORS issue that you try to load the source for the isolate from a different "domain" than the main source.

Comment: Günter, correct, it is a CORS issue. When running the production code from a client chrome with --disable-web-security, the CORS issue is ignored.  My question is can I execute ```pub run test -pchrome``` in some manner such that the --disable-web-security is used when launching chrome.

Comment: Currently not. https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/391 might allow that eventually. Maybe you can create batch file that starts Chrome with the options you want and set the path so `pub run test` finds this first.